# Using guard with JRuby on Windows fails

Tags: rspec, jruby, guard

I'm trying to set up Guard on Windows with JRuby and I'm getting this output:

```
$ guard
You must 'gem install win32console' to use color on Windows
WARNING: You are using Guard outside of Bundler, this is dangerous and could not
 work. Using `bundle exec guard` is safer.
Guard uses Notifu to send notifications.
Guard is now watching at 'C:/Workspace/OE_11/CyberTrack_Rails3'
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!

Running all specs
bundler: command not found: rspec
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
>
```

If I just type the command 'rspec', things do work. So what am I missing here?

```
$ rspec
←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m


Finished in 1.39 seconds
←[32m8 examples, 0 failures←[0m
```

I added the path to rspec.bat to my PATH environment variable.

By the way, I'm working on Windows. On Ubuntu I got everything working in no time...

UPDATE
Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2.rc1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'

gem 'jruby-openssl'
gem 'json'

group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
end

group :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fchange', '0.0.5'
  gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  #gem 'win32console', '1.3.0'
end
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyrhino'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a `bundler` bug as I get the same error if I run:

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

I manage to make it work commenting and adding some code to `guard-rspec` source file.

Open file:

```
C:\jruby-1.6.7\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\guard-rspec-0.6.0\lib\guard\rspec\runner.rb
```

Obs: Note that this path might be diferent on you machine. Anyway, just go to the source of the `guard-rspec` gem and open the `runner.rb` file.

And change the `rspec_command` to this:

```
  def rspec_command(paths, options={})
    warn_deprectation(options)

    cmd_parts = []
    cmd_parts << "rvm #{options[:rvm].join(',')} exec" if options[:rvm].is_a?(Array)
    cmd_parts << "bundle exec" if (bundler? && options[:binstubs] == true && options[:bundler] != false) || (bundler? && options[:bundler] != false)
    cmd_parts << "'"
    cmd_parts << rspec_exec(options)
    cmd_parts << options[:cli] if options[:cli]
    cmd_parts << "-f progress" if options[:cli].nil? || !options[:cli].split(/[\s=]/).any? { |w| %w[-f --format].include?(w) }
    #cmd_parts << "-r #{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/formatters/notification_#{rspec_class.downcase}.rb -f Guard::RSpec::Formatter::Notification#{rspec_class}#{rspec_version == 1 ? ":" : " --out "}/dev/null" if options[:notification] != false
    cmd_parts << "--failure-exit-code #{failure_exit_code}" if failure_exit_code_supported?(options)

    cmd_parts << paths.join(' ')
    cmd_parts << "'"

    cmd_parts.join(' ')
  end
```

The changes I made:

```
 1. commented on of the lines
 2. Added 2 code line to add "quotes" to the string builder.
```

It works here, so it should work on your machine as well.
I open an issue on bundler https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1689 for the issue.

Comment: Still getting the same error... But, I trace out the cmd_parts and it says: bundle exec rspec -f progress --failure-exit-code 2 spec spec'  Now, if I run bundle exec rspec spec, I get the error: bundler: command not found: rspec... Maybe this is has a different cause? rspec spec works fine, bundle exec rspec spec doesn't work. (on Windows).

Comment: Looked at github, and indeed, bundle exec "rspec spec" works fine. Strange. Guard however still doesn't work, but I just see I forgot to add a line...

Comment: Thx, works fine now, and in the meantime I learned how to debug the gems.

Comment: Btw, exactly the same issue with bundle exec spork --bootstrap. bundle exec "spork --bootstrap" works fine.

Comment: All I'm doing is to run make guard-rspec run the code using the quotes.
did you made any change on my code to make it work on your machine? if so post it in here so it could help others. =]

Comment: Celso, your code works fine. Using bundle exec "rspec spec" works. Thx.